# Rails + CanCan: User should be able to delete own photo, but cannot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

So, I'm using Rails 3 with CanCan for authorization. I want all users to be able to delete photos they created, and I thought I had this set up correctly, but it isn't working...

Here's my Ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    # ONLY REGISTERED USERS CAN DO THESE THINGS
    unless user.nil?

      # ALL REGISTERED USERS CAN DO THESE THINGS
      can :read, [Photo, Context, Focus, LandUse, Vote, Rating, Comment, Profile, Article]
      can :show, Page

      # MEMBERS
      if user.has_role? :member
        can [:create, :read], Photo
        can [:update, :destroy], Photo, :user_id => user.id
        can :create, [Vote, Rating, Comment, Profile]
        can :update, [Vote, Rating, Comment, Profile], :user_id => user.id

        can [:show, :update], User do |u|
          u == user
        end
      end

      # CURATORS
      ...

      # ADMINS
      ...

    end

    # ALL VISITORS CAN DO THESE THINGS
    can :create, [User, Profile]
    can :request_invite, User
    # can :show, Page

  end
end
```

Here's my controller action:

```
def destroy
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

  authorize! :delete, @photo
  @photo.destroy
  redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Photo deleted.'
end
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be `authorize! :destroy, @photo` on your controller's `destroy` action.

Comment: Looks like you got the answer in before mine... I'm voting to remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you're using `load_and_authorize_resource` in your controller you can leave out the

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
authorize! :destroy, @photo
```

as it's already done by CanCan.